# Using Google Datastore with Apache Spark via Datastore Hadoop Connector

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to use Google Datastore with Apache Spark on the Google Cloud Platform, and I'm running into some frustrating issues. I deployed Hadoop on the Google Cloud using `bdutil`, with Hadoop 1, Spark, and the Datastore Connector enabled. I had to use an old version of `bdutil` (version 1.2.1 to be specific) because for some reason the Datastore Connector doesn't seem to be included with the latest version.

I then ran the sample Datastore Connector application on the server as per the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/running-with-datastore-connector. That worked perfectly, and the resulting word counts appeared in the datastore.

I then ran a basic Spark application to count the number of lines in a file within Google Cloud Storage, without using the Datastore Connector, and that also ran fine.

The issue came when I tried to use the Datastore Connector with Spark. The code I used is the following, which just attempts to open a connection to the datastore and no more:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

import com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.datastore.DatastoreHadoopHelper
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

object Main {
  val datasetId = "<redacted>"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc.addJar("/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/lib/datastore-connector-0.14.9-hadoop1.jar")
    println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))

    val helper = new DatastoreHadoopHelper(new Configuration())
    try {
      val ds = helper.createDatastore(datasetId)
      println("Success!")
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => println("Error: " + e.getMessage())
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried it without the `sc.addJar` call. I compiled it to a JAR using SBT, which worked just fine (with the datastore connector JAR file in my `lib` folder), and then I uploaded the JAR file to the server. I ran it by executing the following script on the server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
source hadoop-env-setup.sh

spark-submit sparktest.jar --driver-class-path /home/hadoop/hadoop-install/datastore-connector-0.14.9-hadoop1.jar
```

I also tried it without sourcing the Hadoop environment first. When I ran it, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/datastore/DatastoreHadoopHelper
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:16)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.datastore.DatastoreHadoopHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 11 more
```

And this is despite the datastore JAR showing up in the printed classpath:

```
:/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/lib/gcs-connector-1.3.3-hadoop1.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/datastore-connector-0.14.9-hadoop1.jar:/home/hadoop/spark-install/conf:/home/hadoop/spark-install/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop1.0.4.jar:/home/hadoop/spark-install/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/home/hadoop/spark-install/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/home/hadoop/spark-install/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/conf
```

What am I missing? Is it even possible to use Google Datastore with Spark?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: @NicholasAlbion no, we ended up switching to Amazon Web Services instead of Google, and using Cassandra as a replacement for Google Datastore.

Comment: Thanks for the update Bradley